# Genshi: TemplateSyntaxError: not well-formed (invalid token) with ampersands in <script> tag

Tags: python, pylons, genshi

I'm using Pylons/Genshi, and trying to show 'all recent comments' on my site with a Disqus javascript widget (Disqus is installed on the site, and I can post comments OK).

However, the code below produces a nasty 500 error:

**TemplateSyntaxError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 25, column 121** (line 25 is the `<script>` line).

```
  <div py:def="content">
   <div id="recentcomments" class="dsq-widget">
    <h2 class="dsq-widget-title">Recent Comments</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://disqus.com/forums/wdmmg/recent_comments_widget.js 
    num_items=5&hide_avatars=0&avatar_size=32&excerpt_length=200"></script>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Weirdly, I think it might be something to do with the `&` symbols in the GET request, because using

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://disqus.com/forums/wdmmg/recent_comments_widget.js
    ?num_items=5"></script>
```

in the same line works fine. Does Genshi dislike `&` symbols, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XML, you should encode your ampersands, since they have special meaning.

Correct way to use them in urls is `recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=5&amp;hide_avatars=0&amp;avatar_size=32&amp;excerpt_length=200`

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet you don't have `?` before `num_items` and in the second you do. Try adding it to the first one and check, if it works.